# Few field values are not showing up in the final output, i'm using nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, forms, node-modules, form-data

index.html

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5555/sign" method="POST">
      <div class="main">
        <div class="name-container">
          <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="First Name" id="fname" />
          <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname" />
        </div>
        <div class="gender_date">
          <div class="gen">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="male" />
            <label for="male">Male</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="female" />
            <label for="female">Female</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" id="other" />
            <label for="other">Other</label>
          </div>
          <div class="date-con">
            <input type="date" class="input" id='date' name="bday" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

the post request works properly but the names aren't showing up.
back-end nodejs file => serve.js

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.get("/sign", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello");
});
app.post("/sign", urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.body);
  let student = req.body;
  let students = [];
  students.push(student);
  let data = JSON.stringify(students, null, 2);

  fs.writeFile("./file.json", data, err => console.log("success"));
  console.log(students);
});

const PORT = 5555;
app.listen(PORT, err => {
  console.log(`Server Running at port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

file.json: Output

```
[
  {
    "gender": "male",
    "bday": "1999-07-05"
  }
]
```

The value from "First Name" and "Last Name" fields aren't showing up in the final output.
No matter what I change I couldn't get it to work properly.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: [
  [Object: null prototype] {
    gender: 'female',
    bday: '1999-07-05',
    address1: 'Opp To Govt Urdu School, Uppalli',
    address2: 'Near joy coffee curing',
    email1: 'mohammedimran1999.mi@gmail.com',
    email2: 'mohammedimran1999.mi@gmail.com',
    password: '',
    password2: ''
  }
]

Comment: now compare it with form fields

Comment: everything but the name-value appears here and I have no idea about what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5555/sign" method="POST">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="name-container">
      <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" />
      <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" />
    </div>
    <div class="gender_date">
      <div class="gen">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="male" />
        <label for="male">Male</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="female" />
        <label for="female">Female</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" id="other" />
        <label for="other">Other</label>
      </div>
      <div class="date-con">
        <input type="date" class="input" id='date' name="bday" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: whats different in this?

Comment: I replaced the id attribute with name for the inputs fname and lname. You can still add your id attributes but the name attribute is needed to retrieve the values in node.